# Design REST-API in a correct way

Tags: rest, .net-core

Currently i am building a distributed system which has different services like a service which is representating functionallities of a ERP system. This service is implemented in .NET CORE 2.2 and has different WEB API Endpoints (REST Endpoints).

But now i have some questions about the basic API design. Therefore i added a screenshot of an example. The example shows the "controller" Order. This order-controller creates different REST Endpoints and delivers differents informations about a order. 
[image]
How do you build RESTfull APIs for example:

1. Order exists? (In API Description its api/order/{orderNo}/exists
2. Basic order informations like ordernumber, customer,... (In API Description its api/order/{orderNo}/header)
3. Detailled informations about a order like a partlist (IN API Description its api/order/{orderNo}/partlist)

There is one more question which concerns me. If i get the whole Workschedule information by calling **/api/order/{orderNo}/workschedule** how should i return only one workschedule entry? Currently if implemented the Endpoint **/api/order/{orderNo}/workschedule/{operationNo}** which returns exactly one workschedule entry if the operationNo exists. Is it better to do this by parameter filter like **/api/order/{orderNo}/workschedule?operationNo="OneId"**?

I hope you could share your experiences in designing an RESTfull API and give me some hints for a better API design.

Comment: `/api/order/{orderNo}/workschedule/{operationNo}` is more RESTful than `/api/order/{orderNo}/workschedule?operationNo="OneId"`. Whether it's *better* is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, *How do you build RESTfull [sic] APIs...*. Do you mean how do you implement them?  Or what's the concept of responding to RESTful APIs in general?

Comment: @lurker i know how i could implement it in .net core but how should look like my url correctly?

Comment: The list of endpoints you show seems reasonable to me. Outside of following general guidelines for GET, PUT, and POST, keeping things as simple as possible and consistent is important. Beyond that, it's likely going to be a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, I have not had to stick to a strict restful api. Most of the API's I am writing are not large public ones, they are merely for myself and my small team to consume with our applications. With that being said I still strive to write Restful services and here is how I have handled the examples you have given. I try to think of everything I am returning as a "resource" and that can help in the design phase.

Order Exists:
I have done what you have suggested and it works fine no issue there but an example could be to simply just return a 404 not found. This is what I typically do. I just expose the Get /api/resource/id and return a not found and in the consuming applications i handle accordingly.

> api/order/{orderNo}/header

going back to the resource comment. If header is a resource and it's 1 to 1 with the order than this is exactly what I would do. This is better than just api/header/orderNo in my opinion because order is also a resource and I think it flows better. Same for question 3

for the workorder question. It is all preference but I prefer no query parameters if I can put it in the route like you have. That's exactly how I do it.

I always start with parentResource/id/childResource/id just like you have.

if you have pluralsight Kevin Dockx has a couple great courses that helped me a lot.